# Clean URL's within subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory, clean-urls

After looking a lot into stackoverflow i'm not able to figure it out.
I have a website with the following structure

```
index.php
contact.php
about.html
forum(dir)
   - index.php
   - thread.php
```

What i want my htaccess to do

- Remove .php & .html extension, eg: when you visit contact page the url should be  `www.domain.com/contact/` & `www.domain.com/about/`
- When the user visits the forum the url should be `www.domain.com/forum/thread/10004000/` instead of `www.domain.com/forum/thread?id=10004000`

I'm not sure how to figure it out. I was able to remove the extensions but failed in the `/` "forward slash" part

This is my .htaccess part

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try now as you want it's working on my website http://shantunparmar.in you just need to replace with your file or foldername

Comment: It gives a 403 error.

Comment: can you show me your updated one

Comment: I have updated check once again

Comment: give me a moment i am trying same with my domain

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Gives me a 403 again `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^forum/thread/(.+) /forum/thread?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to remove php extention , same for html you can added

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^forum/thread/(.+) /forum/thread?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this demo `mod_rewrite` [link](https://moz.com/blog/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls)